# How to permanently unhide files from disk?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, administrator

I suddenly burned hidden files on a CD, I tried to unhide the files but always access denied

> 'You will need  to provide administrator permission to change the
>   attributes'

I tried loggin in as an admin, and still couldn't make changes.

Can you help me how can I turn this unhide?

Comment: You're trying to change the properties of files on a CD?  Remember CD is just an abbreviation of CD-ROM, where ROM is `Read Only Memory`.

Comment: I thought that by hiding and unhiding is still possible. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data written to a CD is unchangeable once written. This includes file attributes and permissions that control how the file can bee accessed and viewed.

You can make all hidden files visible for all your storage media by changing a setting in the file browser. Click `Start > File Explorer > View > Options > View`. This should bring you to a window named "Folder Options" in a tab named "View" with a tree of check-box options at the bottom. Search through the list of options to find a folder named `Hidden files and folders` and change the radio button to `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`.

At this point, I would check to see if that is good enough for your purposes. If there are still hidden files and you *really* need to reveal them you may also uncheck the option `Hide protected operating system files` further down in the aforementioned list. However, be aware that almost every folder, including your desktop, contains several hidden files that should not be removed or altered directly.

Comment: Conclusion. It is impossible? *Sad* Thanks for sharing the information.  Fortunately, I can unhide once I copied from disc to pc.

Comment: Ah, thought you needed to view them while still on the optical disk. But yes, it's impossible to remove the hidden flag from a file burned to a CD-ROM. You can get away with it with CD-RWs, but that's a whole other can of worms.